# Phalcon\Mvc\Model::validation() and non-model validators

Tags: php, phalcon

I am working on Model validation using Model::validation() call.

It looks like Model::validate() only accepts validators from **Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator** namespace and crashes when **Phalcon\Validation\Validator** are used:

```
class User extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    protected $email = 'invalid @email.*';

    public function validation()
    {
        // Validator from Model namespace
        $this->validate(new Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Uniqueness(array(
            "field"   => "email",
            "message" => "The email is already registered"
        )));

        // Validator from Validation namespace - causes "BadMethodCallException" - "Wrong number of parameters".
        $this->validate(new Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Between(array(
            "field"   => "counter",
            'minimum' => 10,
            'maximum' => 20,
            "message" => "Invalid value"
        )));   

        $validationHasFailed = $this->validationHasFailed();
        return $validationHasFailed != true;
    }
}
```

This results in **BadMethodCallException - Wrong number of parameters** error.

My next thought was to alter the code as follows:

```
class User extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    protected $email = 'invalid @email.*';

    public function validation()
    {
        // Omitting Uniqueness validator.

        $validation = new Phalcon\Validation();
        $validation->add('email', new Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Email);
        $this->validate($validation);

        $validationHasFailed = $this->validationHasFailed();
        return $validationHasFailed != true;
    }
}
```

However, that code fails to detect invalid value of email field (no validation error occurs).

At the same time, the following email validation works as expected:

```
$validation = new Validation();
$validation->add('email', new EmailValidator());
$messages = $validation->validate([
    'email' => 'bad email @...',
], 'email');
```

Question:

Can I use non-Model validators in Model::validation() call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the answer to my question is NO.

Here's a workaround:

```
public function validation()
{
    /**
     * Validate email address.
     *
     * Looks like there's a difference between model- and non-model validators.
     */
    $emailField = 'email';
    $validation = new Phalcon\Validation;
    $validation->add($emailField, new Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Email);

    /**
     * @var Phalcon\Validation\Message\Group
     */
    if (sizeof($messages = $validation->validate([
        $emailField => $this->email,
    ], $emailField))) {
        $message = new Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Message('Invalid email address.', $emailField);
        $this->appendMessage($message);
    } else {
        /**
         * Only when non-model validators don't fail, get on with model validators
         *
         * Validate email uniqueness.
         */
        $this->validate(new Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Uniqueness([
            'field' => $emailField,
            'message' => 'The email is already registered'
        ]));

    }
    $validationHasFailed = $this->validationHasFailed();

    return $validationHasFailed != true;
}
```

Hope someone finds this useful.