# PhalconPHP: Repeating field collection multiple times and saving to multiple models

Tags: php, phalcon, phalconeye

I am creating a form that has multiple sub-forms inside it. Let me elaborate: I am creating a form for a class in the university. That class has multiple stuff in its model like "name","size", etc.. However, I need to attach students to that class. Students have only two fields in their model: "name" and "type"

I need to be able to control all of this from a single form. So normally in PHP the names of the fields would be something like:

```
'name'
'size'
'student[name][]'
'student[type][]'
'student[name][]'
'student[type][]'
```

Which would collect all of the students' information in arrays, which can later be accessed. In that form I will also need to dynamically add the number of student fields, but I guess that can be done with javascript.

**My questions are**: How do I control such a behaviour in Phalcon? Can I use the builder to create fields like that and can I instruct it that those fields are endless, i.e. no specific amount of students? Will I be able to validate all of the students' names using the validator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Model to form-ready data**

1) In your class model, define a relationship to the student model.

```
class Class extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany('id', 'AppName\Models\Student', 'class_id', array(
           'alias' => 'students'
        ));
    }
}
```

2) In your class controller instantiate the class model and reference the alias "students".

```
$class = new Class::findFirst($classId);
$students = $class->students;

$response = array(
    'class' => $class->toArray(),
    'students' => $students->toArray()
);
```

In case you decide not to use Javascript and create the whole form in Phalcon take a look at [Phalcon/Forms](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/forms.html).

**Saving POST data back to model**

Take a look at [this example](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#storing-related-records).

**Validation**

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442830/phalcon-php-form-and-model-validation) is helpful.